# Dynamically add/remove element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery `.remove` function which removes elements from the DOM but what i was thinking is there any way to get back the deleted elements from the DOM.

```
<div id="parent" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px;">
     I am the parent div.
     <div id="child" style="border: 1px solid green; padding: 10px;">
           I am a child div within the parent div.
     </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="button" value="Remove Element">
```

I have the above code.When the `remove element` button is clicked the `.remove` is used to remove the `child` element of the `Div`.Would it be possible using jquery to get back the elements that has been deleted without refreshing the whole page ?

Comment: get copy of remove element

Comment: Use `$(element).hide()`  and `$(element).show()`  to hide and show elements instead of removing. If you remove something from the DOM, you can't recover it in the future

Comment: create new element and add it, or use show/hide

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude We can do it by using `detach`. we have to hold it in a reference and we can use it later if we want.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy any Examples?Anything?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude The `.detach()` method is the same as `.remove()`, except that `.detach()` keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time. Found this in Docs.

Comment: Ok, is useful. However is weird, IMHO, because the performance seems to be poor manipulating DOM by this way. Hide and show produces the same visual result and is better performance. This is only my opinion, not the real truth `:)`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude hiding and showing elements would create problem when you have multiple elements inside form and you dont want the hidden elements to get submitted.Show/Hide would submit no matter what, i guess this would be helpful in those situations.

Comment: That's true, but I don't see forms in your code, it's because I don't care about it. However, the same effect will be produced by disabled form elements. But in this case,  `detach()` is perfect. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove and add an element by using [`.detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) like below,

```
//selector caching
var parent = $("#parent");

//removing the element and storing it in the parent's dataset
$(".remove").click(function() {
  if ($("#child").length) {
    parent.data("ref", $("#child").detach());
  }
});

//adding back the element by fetching it from the parent's dataset
$(".add").click(function() {
  var elem = parent.data("ref");
  if (elem.length) {
    parent.append(elem);
  }
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ebrxo3dt/)